# Here API: how to obtain list of POI for a specific pair of lat,lng?

Tags: here-api

I am doing the next steps:

1. Convert latitude and longitude to col and row:lat = 55.744644 lon = 37.566463 (2475.422867911111, 1280.6456591047722)
2. Making a request to API and do not receive anything: [https://2.base.maps.ls.hereapi.com/maptile/2.1/maptile/newest/normal.day/19/2475.422867911111/1280.6456591047722/256/png8?apiKey={}&metadata=metaonly&mgen=2&pois](https://2.base.maps.ls.hereapi.com/maptile/2.1/maptile/newest/normal.day/19/2475.422867911111/1280.6456591047722/256/png8?apiKey=%7B%7D&metadata=metaonly&mgen=2&pois)
3. Firstly, how to deal with floats
4. Second, if I floor row and col still receive nothing

Answer (score 0):

> Convert latitude and longitude to col and row:lat = 55.744644 lon = 37.566463 (2475.422867911111, 1280.6456591047722)

How do you calculate col and row? What zoom?

This is the correct formula (see https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#Lon..2Flat._to_tile_numbers_2) I believe:

```
import math
def deg2num(lat_deg, lon_deg, zoom):
  lat_rad = math.radians(lat_deg)
  n = 2.0 ** zoom
  xtile = int((lon_deg + 180.0) / 360.0 * n)
  ytile = int((1.0 - math.asinh(math.tan(lat_rad)) / math.pi) / 2.0 * n)
  return (xtile, ytile)
```

and deg2num(55.744644, 37.566463, 19) returns (316854, 163922)